# trying to play back images from multiple cameras in rxbag causes both videos to flip between cameras

Tags: ros, urdf, rxbag, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two urdf files: one of a robot w/ a front camera and the other of a camera that I have floating in the air as a top view perspective.

The cameras in the xacro files are as follows:
(camera.urdf.xacro)

```
<gazebo reference="camera_optical_frame">
    <sensor:camera name="top_view_camera_sensor">
        <imageSize>640 480</imageSize>
        <imageFormat>R8G8B8</imageFormat>
        <hfov>90</hfov>
        <nearClip>0.01</nearClip>
        <farClip>100</farClip>
        <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
        <controller:gazebo_ros_camera name="top_camera_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
            <imageTopicName>top_view/image_raw</imageTopicName>
            <interface:camera name="top_camera_iface" />
        </controller:gazebo_ros_camera>
    </sensor:camera>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
</gazebo>
```

And the one for the robot is similar:

```
<gazebo reference="base_camera_optical_frame">
    <sensor:camera name="base_camera_sensor">
        <imageSize>640 480</imageSize>
        <imageFormat>R8G8B8</imageFormat>
        <hfov>90</hfov>
        <nearClip>0.01</nearClip>
        <farClip>100</farClip>
        <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
        <controller:gazebo_ros_camera name="base_camera_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
            <imageTopicName>my_robot/camera</imageTopicName>
            <frameName>base_camera_optical_frame</frameName>
        </controller:gazebo_ros_camera>
    </sensor:camera>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
</gazebo>
```

When I try and view the "image" of each camera back in rxbag I get images from both cameras in each video.  Is something wrong in my setup?

Both cameras display fine during runtime with image_view.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12258/trying-to-play-back-images-from-multiple-cameras-in-rxbag-causes-both-videos-to-flip-between-cameras/) by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be related to [this bug](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3755).
You can check with rosbag info if that is the case for your logfile.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) on 2011-12-09**:
Actually that was the problem.  I built rxbag and not rosbag.  Thanks for pointing that out to me!

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-12-08**:
Definitely sounds like it could be the bug that @dornhege pointed to.  Does `rosbag info` show that both of the image topics are in the .bag file?  If you post your .bag somewhere, I can have a look at it.

**Comment by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) on 2011-12-08**:
Looks like a similar problem, but all of my topics were recorded in the bag file.  I made the changes in the patch but still no luck.  Thanks for the response, though!  Any other ideas what it could be?